# JavaScript loop and change variables

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am making an artificial intelligent agent to play google chromes t-rex game and need help creating a loop for the game to continuously play at the moment to begin the game I have to actually press space.

```
document.getElementById("botStatus").addEventListener("change", function() {

  if (this.checked === true) {
    // Activate bot
    var INTERVAL = 2;
    window.tRexBot = setInterval(function() {
      var tRex = Runner.instance_.tRex;
      var obstacles = Runner.instance_.horizon.obstacles;
      var lengthsize = 0;
      var a = 0.1;
      var b = 5;
      var c = 35;
      var d = 160;
      var posWidth = 20;

      // if (!tRex.jumping && (obstacles.length > 0) && (obstacles[0].xPos + obstacles[0].width) <= ((parseInt(Runner.instance_.currentSpeed - 0.1) - 5) * 34 + 160) && (obstacles[0].xPos + obstacles[0].width) > 20) {
      if (!tRex.jumping && (obstacles.length > lengthsize) && (obstacles[0].xPos + obstacles[0].width) <= ((parseInt(Runner.instance_.currentSpeed - a) - b) * c + d) && (obstacles[0].xPos + obstacles[0].width) > posWidth) {
        // console.log(obstacles[0].xPos + obstacles[0].width + " | " + ((parseInt(Runner.instance_.currentSpeed - 0.1) - 5) * 34 + 160));
        tRex.startJump();
      }
    }, INTERVAL);
  } else {
    // Disable bot
    clearInterval(tRexBot);
  }
});
```

what I require is for once the Interval ends, I would like it to take the games current speed and distance of obstacles then either increase or decrease the variables I have set into a new interval, so that it will hopefully learn how to get further and further into the game as it picks up speed...

If this sort of makes sense?

Comment: Some people have done this maybe you can pull the interval info from their github? https://github.com/ivanseidel/IAMDinosaur

Comment: I can't pull too much code from github repositories as i'm doing this for a university module in artificial intelligence i'm really struggling to grasp many concepts if i'm being completely honest. Also,  javascript isn't my most favourite language... thanks for the link though :)

Comment: Any help you get on here will be under the MIT license, which is the same license that the project @Marker posted has. It is free to use for any application. Regardless of whether you get it here or from the project above, you're going to have to cite your source (for academic purposes). Just look at how they do it and extract the relevant parts - you don't need to copy entire files

Answer (score 0):

A number of changes you could make to improve the code.

1) Extract the code for starting/stopping the bot to their own functions

```
var INTERVAL = 2;

function startBot(){
  var bot = {}; //empty bot info
  bot.tRex = Runner.instance_.tRex;
  ....
  bot.posWidth = 20;
  bot.interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!bot.tRex.jumping && (bot.obstacles.length > bot.lengthsize) /*...*/) {
        tRex.startJump();
      }
  },INTERVAL);
  return bot;
}

function stopBot(bot) {
  clearInterval(bot.interval);
}

document.getElementById("botStatus").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.checked === true) {
    window.bot = startBot();
  }
  else {
    stopBot(window.bot);
  }
}
```

2) pass the config parameters into the "startBot" function so you can more easily change it on the outside.

```
var config = { posWidth:20,a: 01,...};

startBot(config);
function startBot(config) {
  var bot = config;
  //....
}
```